# Missing System.Web.UI and System.Web.Security

Tags: c#

I can't compile a project because the namespaces System.Web.UI and System.Web.Security are missing. I can only see System.Web.ApplicationServices, System.Web.Mvc and System.Web.Services when I do add references. Where do I download the missing namespaces?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Go to menu Project -> Add reference and find out the System.Web.dll in the list

[image]

Comment: You mean under the Assembilies menu? I can't see System.Web.dll.

Comment: Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: Then open the Reference dialog from Project -> Add Reference. Then you will be able to find the lib under Assemblies -> Framework. Have a look at my answer edit for details

Comment: I found out by changing the framework profile from .Net Framework 4 Client Profile to .Net Framework 4, System.Web appears in the list. While I can choose System.Web, I'm still unable to choose System.Web.UI.

Comment: If you import System.Web you will be able to use classes in the System.Web.UI namespace bi simply importing that namespace in your code like `using System.Web.UI;`. The System.Web.UI namespace is not in a different library

Answer (score 27):

I don't know about System.Web.UI, but System.Web.Security moved to the System.Web.ApplicationServices assembly in .NET 4.0 Framework.

Answer (score 4):

Following Kinderchocolate's suggestion, I switched to ".Net Framework 4" in my project's Properties (VS 2010), and that caused "System.Web" to appear in the assemblies list.  From then on I was finally able to use System.Web.UI.

So I'm not sure what failed for kinderchocolate, but his change worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can add System.Web.ApplicationServices assembly in .NET 4.5 Framework.

using System.Web.ApplicationServices;

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I'm using Visual Studio 2015, Right click to Project References - Add Reference - (Assemblies) - Check in list "System.Web.ApplicationServices" - Click OK

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Kinderchocolate is correct. Once you add the Reference `System.Web` to your project, then in the code you can add `using System.Web.UI` and all sub-components of `System.Web.UI`, e.g. `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls`.

Answer (score 1):

you can go to : project -> proprieties -> and change the Framework from Client profile to .Net 4, if it doesn't work you can add the reference manually. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Add references `System.Web.Extensions` and `System.Web.Extensions.Design` in 4.6.1 
if you miss `ListView` or `LinqDataSource`